# convertir mi pc en un servidor con xampp

Tags: apache, xampp, servidor

quiero entrar a un proyecto desde otro dispositivo ya sea un pc o un celular, yo mire como podia hacerlo con apache de xampp y era modificando el archivo http-xampp.conf y ponerle esta lina al final:

```
#
# New XAMPP security concept
#
# Close XAMPP security section here
<LocationMatch “^/(?i:(?:security))”>
Order deny,allow
#Deny from all
#Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8
Allow from all
ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
 # Close XAMPP sites here
 <LocationMatch “^/(?i:(?:xampp|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server- 
 status|server-info))”>
 Order deny,allow
 #Deny from all
 #Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8
 Allow from all
 ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
 </LocationMatch>
```

luego desde el otro dispositivo digito la direccion ip de mi maquina y el nombre del proyecto pero no me deja entrar me sale este error:

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or 
is temporarily unavailable.

Most likely causes:
The directory or file specified does not exist on the Web server.
The URL contains a typographical error.
A custom filter or module, such as URLScan, restricts access to the file.

Things you can try:
Create the content on the Web server.
Review the browser URL.
Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code and 
see which module is calling SetStatus. For more information about creating a 
tracing rule for failed requests, click here.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       MapRequestHandler
 Handler       StaticFile
Error Code     0x80070002
Requested URL      http://localhost:80/olPrueba2/index.php/Admin
Physical Path      C:\inetpub\wwwroot\olPrueba2\index.php\Admin
Logon Method       Anonymous
 Logon User    Anonymous

More Information:
This error means that the file or directory does not exist on the server. 
Create 
the file or directory and try the request again.
View more information »
```

y cuando solo cargo la direccion ip, es decir sin el nombre del proyecto al que quiero ingresar me carga xampp normal osea que si esta conectado. pueden ayudarme a resolver este error o si conocen otra manera de hacer mi pc como un servidor seria muy bueno para mi...

Gracias

Comment: ¿Por qué aparece en el error "IIS Web Core" si estás con xampp que usa apache?

Comment: ¿Cuál es la dirección que escribes para acceder a tu página desde fuera? (si no quieres publicarla acá, puedes indicar la estructura, reemplazando el IP por una de demo).

Comment: Oh, es cierto lo que pregunta @blonfu: ¿será que tienes instalados 2 servidores web en tu PC?

Comment: no creo que tenga dos servidores, yo solo he instalado xampp.  ahora desactive el firewall de windows, y nada, lo que uso para acceder desde otro pc es en google chrome pongo 
     http://00.000.000.00/Proyecto/,suponiedo que los ceros son los numeros de mi ip, y ya no me sale el erros que les puse, sino que me dice que tardo demaciado tiempo en responder.

Comment: Esto me hace pensar en la configuración que tiene en el archivo `httpd.conf` de Apache la variable `DocumentRoot`. Te sugiero estudies su [documentación](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot), y así revisar cómo está configurado en tu Apache. Si no es ese el parámetro, tal vez te guíe a encontrar el que necesitas realmente.

Comment: la URL es un poco rara también `http://localhost:80/olPrueba2/index.php/Admin` index.php es un archivo no una carpeta, ¿Cómo puede tener dentro una carpeta o archivo llamado *Admin*?. El error es un 404, por lo tanto no encuentra el recurso, lo que hace suponer que la ruta no es correcta